# pandas: check whether an element is in dataframe or given column leads to strange results

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, element

I am doing some data handling based on a DataFrame with the shape of `(135150, 12)` so double checking my results manually is not applicable anymore.

I encountered some 'strange' behavior when I tried to check if an element is part of the dataframe or a given column.

This behavior is reproducible with even smaller dataframes as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    

start = 1e-3
end = 2e-3
step = 0.01e-3
arr = np.arange(start, end+step, step)

val = 0.0019

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['example_value'])

print(val in df) # prints `False`
print(val in df['example_value']) # prints `True`
print(val in df.values) # prints `False`
print(val in df['example_value'].values) # prints `False`
print(df['example_value'].isin([val]).any()) # prints `False`
```

Since I am a very beginner in data analysis I am not able to explain this behavior.

I know that I am using different approaches involving different datatypes (like `pd.Series`, `np.ndarray` or `np.array`) in order to check if the given value exists in the dataframe. Additionally when using `np.array` or `np.ndarray` the machine accuracy comes in play which I am aware of in mind.

However, at the end, I need to implement several functions to filter the dataframe and count the occurrences of some values, which I have done several times before based on boolean columns in combination with performed operations like `>` and `<` successfully.

But in this case I need to filter by the exact value and count its occurrences which after all lead me to the issue described above.

So could anyone explain, what's going on here?

Comment: Floating point issues maybe?

Comment: @Divakar: For sure. That's what I meant by 'machine accuracy comes in play'. However, I don't know how to solve that in combination with a pandas dataframe. Having numpy arrays I would use `np.isclose()` but in this case I am working on a DataFrame or Series object which I could convert to numpy objects for sure. However converting to numpy objects and back to pandas objects seems to be a very dirty workaround.

Comment: `val in df` checks for columns (`'example_value' in df` returns True), `val in df['example_value']` checks for index (`1 in df['example_value']` returns True) For your case, since the index is integer, it converts the val to integer and then checks - so the false positive (a bug maybe). The rest seems to be related to floating point. There is no need to convert back and forth, you can directly use np.isclose on a series or a dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying issue, as Divakar suggested, is floating point precision. Because DataFrames/Series are built on top of numpy, there isn't really a penalty for using numpy methods though, so you can just do something like:

```
df['example_value'].apply(lambda x: np.isclose(x, val)).any()
```

or

```
np.isclose(df['example_value'], val).any()
```

both of which correctly return `True`.

Comment: The second answer is much more efficient. In general, and particularly when using numpy functions on pandas columns, apply is an order of magnitude slower. In the example above, it's trivial, but, it's something that should be pointed out.

Comment: Very good point; thanks. The `apply` approach will call `np.isclose` once per element, whereas the second only calls it once for the entire Series. Since numpy is internally much more efficient than pure Python, you'll save a lot of time by only making the single call.